ImageInspectError while running pods in Colima-docker
I'm trying to run a simple image in pods with Colima and docker runtime.
I'm able pull image in docker and run it successfully but can't run it in pod..Always getting Image InspectError
Also tried to pull local image for pod..
Deployment.yaml.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-python-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-python-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-python-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-python-app
        image: localhost:5000/my-python-app:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

Events of logs in pod:
Type     Reason         Age                     From               Message

Normal   Scheduled      5m58s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/my-python-app-696d5b745c-lx4jq to colima
Warning  Failed         3m55s (x12 over 5m54s)  kubelet            Error: ImageInspectError
Warning  InspectFailed  52s (x26 over 5m54s)    kubelet            Failed to inspect image "localhost:5000/my-python-app:latest": Id or size of image "localhost:5000/my-python-app:latest" is not set
Basically I need Run Kubernetes pods in Local... In Mac m1
Please help to resolve the above issue
